# How do I get the channel name the command was sent to

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

I am attempting to get the name of the channel the command was sent to. I am trying to check and see if the channel name the command was sent to is equal to the one I want to require the command to be sent to.

```
if (message.guilds.channels.name !== "suggestions") return message.channel.send("Please use the \"#suggestions\" text channel");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message.channel.name
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel

It's all listed on the discord.js website under the message class